Get/Modify Rows In AspNetUserRoles Through Using An Extended Class For IdentityUserRoles
I am currently working on creating a feature that gives users the ability to switch between profiles. To implement this, I have decided to extend IdentityUserRoles with a new class as follows:
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeactivated { get; set; }
}

I created/ran an ef migration without issue and can see the new columns in the AspNetUserRoles table.
I have also extended the IdentityUser as follows:
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

Following the advice at this StackOverflow question, I setup my context as follows:
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
           .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
           .WithMany(r => r.Users)
           .UsingEntity<ApplicationUserRole>
           (au => au.HasOne<ApplicationRole>().WithMany(role => role.UserRoles).HasForeignKey(u => u.RoleId),
           au => au.HasOne<ApplicationUser>().WithMany(user => user.UserRoles).HasForeignKey(r => r.UserId))
           .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>()
        .HasOne(ur => ur.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>()
        .HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
        .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);

However, the UserRoles property never populates and remains null. I have tried using the following when the user authenticates through the userManager:
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(username);
            if (user != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
            {
                await _context.Entry(user).Collection(x => x.UserRoles).LoadAsync();
                return user;
            }

But this simply converts ApplicationUser.UserRoles to an empty array. How can I go about retrieving the data from the AspNetUserRoles table and later modify the added columns?

This seems like an odd way to setup many to many relationships in EF.
You have ApplicationUserRole which I would assume is your many-to-many table.
I would remove reference to Roles from ApplicationUser, and just leave a 1-to-many reference to ApplicationUserRole in ApplicationUser.
You would then get all Roles for User by Including all ApplicationUserRole.User == "YourUser".
Also not really sure what you mean by UserRoles never populate, it should populate when you assign UserAndRole to it.
If the model is working it could also be problem with lazy loading
Fluent API, many-to-many in Entity Framework Core
